# Web load testing - what does a wavy response time graph indicate?

Tags: graph, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am running a load test on an API using JMeter. When I host the API on the same pc as the test (the database is remote though) I get ok results. 
However, when I tried running the load test through the same API but hosted on a different pc on the same network, I got this wavy pattern in my test results.

[image: wavy pattern in web load test results graph]

Each of the four grouped lines are response times for a particular API endpoint and the blue line is active thread count. 
The question is: does this wavy pattern mean anything? This pattern isn't visible when the API is hosted on the same machine as the test.
The results are very different and I am thinking this pattern might be correlated to the problem.

I used 200 active threads and no specific configuration which would produce the requests in this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pay attention to the following points:

1. [Connect Time and Latency metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html), **Elapsed Time** is a sum of **Connect Time**, **Latency** and the **actual server response time** so these "waves" might be caused by [networking issues](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0).
2. It might be indicating the application under tests is doing i.e. [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) or using [swap file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Swap_files_and_partitions) which is much slower than memory due to lack of resources Make sure that it has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network and Disk IO. These metrics can be checked using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/). The same is applicable for JMeter, if JMeter will not be able to send requests fast enough - you will see throughput dropdowns.
3. The most efficient way to get to the bottom of the issue is running your application under [profiling tool telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)), this will allow you to
   identify the heaviest functions, largest objects in heap, etc.
4. Consider checking your database as well and detect slow queries as the issue might be caused by database issues (including networking layer)

Comment: Thank you for such insightful answer. The problem was in a slow sql query which was not in our versioned code so I did not have it locally.